# OSGeo4W and GDAL - gdal2tiles.py error

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo4w, gdal2tiles

Wondering why gdal2tiles is throwing errors, I've added the gdaldata and gdalplugins environmental variables and my python is at Python27/ArcGIS10.3/, and am wondering if that is messing with the OSGeo4W python located in the C:\OSGeo4W\bin folder, or do I need to direct my environment variables every time I want to use OSGeo4W vs. ArcGIS python versions?

Or is it working and the error I'm seeing below has to do with something else totally separate?

OSGEO4W home is C:\OSGeo4W\

```
                   -={ OSGeo4W Shell Commands }=-

       bmp2tiff             listgeo              raw2tiff
       cs2cs                nad2bin              rgb2ycbcr
       curl                 ncdump               rpcgen
       dllupdate            ncgen                rpcinfo
       fax2ps               nearblack            testepsg
       fax2tiff             nircmd               textreplace
       gdaladdo             nircmdc              thumbnail
       gdalbuildvrt         ogdi_import          tiff2bw
       gdaldem              ogdi_info            tiff2pdf
       gdalenhance          ogr2ogr              tiff2ps
       gdalinfo             ogrinfo              tiff2rgba
       gdallocationinfo     ogrlineref           tiffcmp
       gdalmanage           ogrtindex            tiffcp
       gdalserver           opj_compress         tiffcrop
       gdalsrsinfo          opj_decompress       tiffdither
       gdaltindex           opj_dump             tiffdump
       gdaltransform        osgeo4w-setup-work   tiffinfo
       gdalwarp             osgeo4w-setup        tiffmedian
       gdal_contour         pal2rgb              tiffset
       gdal_grid            portmap              tiffsplit
       gdal_rasterize       ppm2tiff             w9xpopen
       gdal_translate       proj                 xmlcatalog
       geod                 psql                 xmllint
       geotifcp             python               xxmklink
       gif2tiff             pythonw
       gltpd                ras2tiff


       epsg_tr           gdalmove          make-bat-for-py
       esri2wkt          gdal_auth         mkgraticule
       gcps2vec          gdal_calc         o-help
       gcps2wld          gdal_edit         o4w_env
       gdal2tiles        gdal_fillnodata   pct2rgb
       gdal2xyz          gdal_merge        rgb2pct
       gdalchksum        gdal_polygonize   setup-test
       gdalcompare       gdal_proximity    setup
       gdalident         gdal_retile
       gdalimport        gdal_sieve

GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10

C:\Users\maugust\Desktop>gdal2tiles.py C:\Users\maugust\Desktop\example_tifs\Pie
rce_2010_84.tif C:\Users\maugust\Desktop\example_tifs\tilegdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal2tiles.py", line 2278, in <module>
    gdal2tiles.process()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal2tiles.py", line 482, in process
    self.open_input()
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdal2tiles.py", line 856, in open_input
    self.out_ds.SetMetadataItem('NODATA_VALUES','%i %i %i' % (self.in_nodata[0],
self.in_nodata[1],self.in_nodata[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Users\maugust\Desktop>
```

Comment: It's not the path variable - your error outputs show that it's finding the right .py file.

Answer (score 4):

This same error threw me off, too. Adding NODATA transparency value parameter to the call fixed it for me, so instead of

```
gdal2tiles.py -z 1-10 ~/hfp_wgs/hdr.adf hpf-tiles
```

I called

```
gdal2tiles.py -z 1-10 -a 0,0,0 ~/hfp_wgs/hdr.adf hpf-tiles
```

and it started working. Note that the value had to be three numbers, one for each of RGB channels.

Comment: I have a grayscale TIF, and was running into this error: using your `-a` tip works, but I get the warning: `NODATA_VALUES metadata item doesn't have the same number of values as the number of bands. Ignoring it for mask.` Is this ok?